# PHP Blade | print specific Data only if equal a certain value

Tags: php, laravel-blade

In one of my PHP Blade file, I'm building a foreach which prints records | rows.

I would like to print this two :

```
            @if(isset($products->{'Décoration Chocolat et fruits'})) {{ $products->{'Décoration Chocolat et fruits'}.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'Décoration petites fleurs'})) {{ $products->{'Décoration petites fleurs'}.' | ' }} @endif @if(isset($products->Décoration)) {{ $products->Décoration.' | ' }} @endif
```

only if the value of

```
            @if(isset($products->Type)) {{ $products->Type.' | ' }} @endif
```

is equal to a certain 'value'

Hereafter my foreach :

```
@foreach($content['order'] as $products)

    <tr> 
        <td>
            @if(isset($products->Type)) {{ $products->Type.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->Nom)) {{ $products->Nom.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'# Personnes'})) {{ $products->{'# Personnes'}.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->Inscription)) {{ $products->Inscription.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'Décoration Chocolat et fruits'})) {{ $products->{'Décoration Chocolat et fruits'}.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'Décoration petites fleurs'})) {{ $products->{'Décoration petites fleurs'}.' | ' }} @endif @if(isset($products->Décoration)) {{ $products->Décoration.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->Poids)) {{ $products->Poids.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'Assortiment 1'})) {{ $products->{'Assortiment 1'}.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'Assortiment 2'})) {{ $products->{'Assortiment 2'}.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'Assortiment 3'})) {{ $products->{'Assortiment 3'}.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'Assortiment 4'})) {{ $products->{'Assortiment 4'}.' | ' }} @endif 
            @if(isset($products->{'Couleur Ruban'})) {{ $products->{'Couleur Ruban'}.' | ' }} @endif 
             Prix : CHF @if(isset($products->Total)) {{ number_format($products->Total, 2) }} @endif
        </td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
```

I'm stuck, would appreciate your expertise. Thanks, Marc

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no difference, just the same as you normally would in your if statement

Comment: `!empty($products->Type) && $products->Type === 'whatever value you need to satisfy'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION from @Ghost**

Thank you @Ghost, for your short and effective answer which works well for me :

SOLUTION :

!empty($products->Type) && $products->Type === 'whatever value you need to satisfy'